# Geolocalizing archive aerial photos

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, aerial-photography

I have ~125 analog **aerial photographs** from **1937** (examples below) and need to **reconstruct their locations** where the images were taken for a research project. Unfortunately, little is known about them: neither if they are all taken at the same altitude nor if the images are oriented to the north. They could have been taken anywhere within the [Germany's borders at the time](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:German_Empire_1937_adm_location_map.svg). And the images were printed in different sizes and thus differ in print/scan resolution. Image recognition won't work because the spatial structures have changed too much since then, but I would imagine that a large part of the land parcels and streets / squares have remained the same.
I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08323.pdf) by Dragos Costea and Marius Leordeanu describing **"Aerial image geolocalization from recognition and matching of roads and intersections"**, and so far this looks to be the most promising approach for my problem, as it doesn't rely on image recognition. It would be a success for me if I can locate about 7-10% of the images.

However, since I am not a specialist and the implementation / testing means a lot of effort for me, I wonder if you think the project is realistic in principle or even know an alternative method that would be worth trying?

[image: Example image]

[image: Example image]

[image: Example image]

**Update:** With the help of a known subject (Monument to the Battle of the Nations) I can know determine that the images are not oriented to the north.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a case for either A: artificial intelligence (propably the approach mentioned in the paper) or B: citicen science. At least for "prominent" locations (as no. 1 seems to be), the last approach could be successful and a lot of academic libraries, archives etc. already have projects in that domain. For images lice no. 2 and 3, chances will probably be larger using AI - indeed, I guess the shape of the road network is very characteristic and could be compared with recent data - or old maps from the 1920's, 1930's.

Comment: No. 2 by the way is Völkerschlachtendenkmal: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%B6lkerschlachtdenkmal, see aerial image here: https://www.google.de/maps/place/51%C2%B018'44.3%22N+12%C2%B024'47.4%22E/@51.3125517,12.411319,658m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.312313!4d12.413169

Comment: Yes, it is in Leipzig, I can confirm it. A beautiful place by the way)

Comment: The shadow of trees, buildings etc. can be a hint about Cardinal direction: in Germany, the sun always comes from SE - S - SW. And probably such kind of images were shot not at early morning and late evening and probably in the warm season (April to September). So assume sun being in the south +/-45 degrees. Also look around which institutions already have aerial images from the region of your interest posted and get in touch, maybe you could use their geolocation for comparision (by machine, if possible).

Comment: Yes! Unfortunately this is the only image with such characteristic elements like the Monument to the Battle of the Nations. But the recommendations of using the shadows is very good. Also I will look into finding map data from the 20s, 30s! Thank you so far!

Comment: Also have a look at https://www.oldmapsonline.org/ , there is a section for Germany: https://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Germany. On the timeline, select something like 1900 to 1950 and maybe also limit map scale to find maps in a spatial resolution and from the epoch you're interested in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtKU7.jpg - https://www.kartenportal.ch/ works similarily. https://www.davidrumsey.com/ might be less interesting for Germany.

Comment: With the site mentioned before, you can find very detailed maps e.g. like this one from the 1930s from Eastern Prussia (new Russian Kaliningrad district): http://www.deutschefotothek.de/documents/obj/71051831/df_dk_0010001_1596 - Deutsche Fotothek has a lot of such detailed maps, so it might be worth contacting them.